# Preg Replace php

Tags: php, regex

I've got the phrase "rising_car_insurance_costs.php" I want to use preg_replace to remove the .php:

```
  $news = preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+[.php]/', '$1 + ''', end($parts));
```

I also want to replace the _ with a space which I can do but I also want to make the first letter a capital letter (if it's a letter) -is that even possible?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 2):

No need for regular expression

> I want to use preg_replace to remove the .php:

```
$news = basename(end($parts), '.php');
```

I guess `$parts` mean, that you splitted a path using `explode()` with `/`. When you use `basename()` you can avoid this step too.

> I also want to replace the _ with a space

```
$news = str_replace('_', ' ', $news);
```

> I also want to make the first letter a capital letter

```
$news = ucfirst($news);
```

Comment: and for the _ removal use str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$news = ucfirst(trim(preg_replace('/(?:_|\.php$)/i', ' ', end($parts)));
```

To explain:

- [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/ucfirst) uppercases the first character in a string
- [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) trims spaces from the beginning and end of the string
- `preg_replace()` replaces the following regular expression (case insensitive, `/i`) with whitespace

  - `(?:...)` is a non-capturing expression, useful for using the `|` later
  - `_` means any "_" character
  - `|` means "or"
  - `\.php$` means the sequence ".php" at the end of the string

Comment: @user990580, it's a [subpattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php), but without capturing. If you don't add `?:`, then the match will be stored in `\1`. This way, it just means it won't be stored (more for performance reasons than anything else).

Answer (score 0):

Easier without preg_replace:

```
$without_php = str_replace( '.php', '', end( $parts ) )
$without_underscores = str_replace( '_', ' ', $without_php );
$uppercased = ucfirst( $without_underscored);
```

All in one:

```
$result = ucfirst( str_replace( array( '.php', '_' ), array( '', ' '), end( $parts ) ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to use `preg_replace_callback` and do the other stuff there:

```
$news = preg_replace_callback('/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+)[.php]$/', 'rewrite',

function rewrite($match) {
    $str = $match[1];
    ... strtr("_", " ");
    ... ucwords(); 
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: I thought their was a way to use preg_replace with $ to match various parts of a string???

Comment: Of course there is. But uppercasing a letter just with a single regex is not feasible. And you seem to have some confusion with the `/e` syntax, so _callback is advisable.